What's the background behind "They gave us the land"?
In Juan Rulfo's short story "They gave us the land" (part of the collection The Burning Plain and Other Stories, of which the Spanish original is available online and George D. Schade's English translation is freely available to borrow from the Internet Archive), four men are walking across the dry plain. The timespan of the story itself is short, a few hours at most, but there's clearly a lot of backstory which is only hinted at.

There are four of us. I count them: two in front, and two behind. I look further back and don't see anybody. Then I say to myself, "There are four of us." Not long ago, at about eleven, there were over twenty, but little by little they've been scattering away until just this knot of us is left.

What happened to the others? How did so many of their companions "scatter away" in the course of a single day? Is the implication that many died during their trek, or were they all going to different places rather than really travelling together as a group?

And here we are. The four of us on foot. Before, we used to ride on horseback and carry a rifle slung over our shoulder. Now we don't even carry the rifle.
I've always thought that taking away our rifles was a good thing. Around these parts it's dangerous to go around armed. You can get killed without warning if you're seen with your thirty-thirty strapped on. But horses are another matter. If we'd come on horses we would already be tasting the green river water, and walking our full stomachs around the streets of the town to settle our dinner. We'd already have done that if we still had all those horses. But they took away our horses with the rifles.

Who is "they" that took away the horses and rifles? This probably relates to the historical context which I don't entirely get but which contemporary Mexican readers would certainly have understood. The story also mentions an "official" who assigned the useless land to them, and their conversation mentions "the Center" and "the government" and "the large-estate owners"; was it this Centre (part of the government?) that took away their horses and rifles, and why?

The story contains several hints at its historical context. The taking away of rifles (or carbines in Weatherford's translation) sounds like a reference at disarmament after a war of rebellion. The taking away of horses is plausible as part of the same disarmament measures.
What the conflict might be about is hinted at elsewhere in the story:

They told us:
— From the town all to here is yours.
We asked:
— Yes, the llano. Every bit of the Llano Grande.
(…)
— But there's no water. Not even for a single sip.
— What about the rainy season? No one said anything about giving you irrigated land. (…)
[Later, the delegado adds,]
— Then put your complaint in writing. Now off you go. It's the large estates you need to fight against, not the Government that's giving you the land.

(Juan Rulfo: The Burning Plain. Translated by Douglas J. Weatherford. University of Texas Press, 2024, pages 5–6.)
This identifies the context as agrarian reform. Juan Rulfo was born in and grew up in or between conflicts that involved demands for land reform: the Mexican Revolution (1910–1920, or 1910–1917 according to other sources) and the Cristero War or Rebellion (1926–1929).
The article The Causes of the Mexican Revolution: A Fight for Land and Rights on MexicoHistory.com explains (emphasis mine):

One of the principal causes of the Mexican Revolution was the severe inequity in land ownership that characterized the late 19th and early 20th centuries. Under the rule of President Porfirio Díaz, who held power for most of this period, land concentration became a stark issue. Díaz favored the wealthy elite and foreign interests, often through the ruthless privatization and expropriation of communal lands that had long belonged to indigenous and rural communities. This redistribution of land favored the large estates, or haciendas, while leaving an overwhelming majority of peasants landless and struggling for survival. The agrarian policies implemented during Díaz’s regime exacerbated class disparities, leading to widespread resentment, particularly in rural areas where impoverished farmers found themselves increasingly marginalized.

The "large estates" mentioned by the delegado suggests that the land distribution remains unequal (as is already clear from the decision to palm off people with a large stretch of desert).
The Cristero War was not primarily about land reform but started as a reponse to changes in the Consitution in 1917 and a later executive decree by President Plutarco Elías Calles to enforce Article 130 of the Constitution. This was one of several articles that seriously restricted the Roman Catholic Church in Mexico. Article 3 prohibited churches to own property and transferred all church property to the state. Many of the peasants who took up arms fought for land reform. However, even though Calles had called form during his election campaign in 1924, he turned out to against land reform when in power. For this reason, the aftermath of the Mexican Revolution seems the more plausible historical context for the story.
Why most of the other men of the initial party don't continue with the others is something I can only guess. Possibly, they all wanted to make sure whether there was any part of the llano that could be put to use (but had not noticed before?) and gave up, concluding that the search was pointless.
